# Substring a CSV header to create a new header

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file that doesn't have headers, so I add headers:

```
$file = "<path to file>"
$list = Import-Csv $file -Header Unit, IP, Hostname
```

The results look like this:

```
Unit               IP           Hostname
----               --           --------  
1234 Camden London 192.168.1.1  Server1
```

I wish to give "Camden London" it's own header, whilst maintaining "1234" to the "Unit" column.

```
Unit Town          IP           Hostname
---- ----          --           --------  
1234 Camden London 192.168.1.1  Server1
```

I can separate them into their own list but don't know where to start in doing this inline with `Import-Csv` - can anyone help please?

```
$Unit = $list | Select {$_.Unit.Substring(0,4)}
$Town = $list | Select {$_.Unit.Substring(5)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to create the split fields and exclude the original `Unit` field:

```
Import-Csv $file -Header Unit, IP, Hostname |
    Select-Object -Property @{n='Unit';e={$_.Unit.Substring(0,4)}},
        @{n='Town';e={$_.Unit.Substring(5)}}, * -Exclude Unit
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can recreate object :

```
Import-Csv $file -Header Unit, IP, Hostname | %{
[pscustomobject]@{
    Unit=$_.Unit.Substring(0,4)
    Town=$_.Unit.Substring(5)
    IP=$_.IP
    Hostname=$_.Hostname
}

}
```